# Average of even numbers in a list

Tags: python-3.x

Devise an algorithm to compute the following: given a list of numbers, find the average of the even numbers in the list, e.g., in [1,2,4,1,2,9,4], the even numbers are 2,4,2 and 4, and the average of them is (2+4+2+4)/4=3.

Comment: -1 We help you with your homework but don't do it for you. Here's how you ask a better question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

```py
import statistics

l = [1,2,4,1,2,9,4]
result = statistics.mean(x for x in l if x % 2 == 0)
```

The core of this solution is [`statistics.mean()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.mean) which calculates the mean value of an iterable of numbers and the [list comprehension with an if](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-list-comprehensions-in-python-3).

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is the following:

```
l = [1,2,4,1,2,9,4]
even = list(filter(lambda elem: elem % 2 == 0, l))
result = sum(even) / len(even)
```

First you use [`filter`](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/map_filter.html#filter) to find all evens and then you calculate the average.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Sample list of even_numbers and odd_number
even_numbers = [2,4,6,8,10,12,14]
odd_number = [1,3,5,7,9,11,13]

# Calculate the average for even numbers
if even_numbers:
avg_even = sum(even_numbers) / len(even_numbers)
else:
avg_even = 0  # Handle the case when there are no even numbers

# Calculate the average for odd numbers
if odd_number:
avg_odd = sum(odd_number) / len(odd_number)
else:
avg_odd = 0  # Handle the case when there are no odd numbers

print(f"Average of even numbers: {avg_even}")
print(f"Average of odd numbers: {avg_odd}")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# Sample list of even_numbers and odd_number
list_numbers = [2,4,6,8,10,12,14,1,3,5,7,9,11,13]
even_num= []   #empty strings even_number
odd_num=[]     #empty string odd number
# Calculate the average for even numbers
for i in list_numbers:
    if i%2 == 0:
        even_num.append(i)   #append function is used to add value of list in empty string
    else:
        odd_num.append(i)

# Calculate the average for even numbers
if even_num:
    avg_even = sum(even_num) / len(even_num)   # Sum function will add the value of even_num and length will check the length of list
else:
    avg_even = 0  # Handle the case when there are no even numbers

# Calculate the average for odd numbers
if odd_num:
    avg_odd = sum(odd_num) / len(odd_num)
else:
    avg_odd = 0  # Handle the case when there are no odd numbers

print(f"Average of even numbers: {avg_even}")
print(f"Average of odd numbers: {avg_odd}")
```